# postgreSQL - how to filter by json_agg value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have join table between t_table and s_table.
there are many to many relationships between them.

s_table

| id | s_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

t_table

| id | t_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |

t_id_s_id_table

| s_id | t_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

First, I aggregated t_value group by s_table id by this query

```
SELECT 
  t_id_s_id_table.s_id,
  JSON_AGG(t_value) AS json_agg
FROM
  t_id_s_id_table
LEFT JOIN
  t_table
ON
 t_table.id = t_id_s_id_table.t_id
GROUP BY 
 t_id_s_id_table.s_id
```

And I got this result.

| s_id | json_agg |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100, 200 |
| 2 | 200, 300 |
| 3 | 100, 300 |

### What I would like to do

I want to obtain all s_ids whose associated json_agg value includes 100.
(It means s_id = 1 and 3)

I tried the following query

```
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      t_id_s_id_table.s_id,
      JSON_AGG(t_value) AS json_agg
    FROM
      t_id_s_id_table
    LEFT JOIN
      t_table
    ON
     t_table.id = t_id_s_id_table.t_id
    GROUP BY 
     t_id_s_id_table.s_id
  )
  WHERE COUNT(json_agg = 100) > 0
```

but it doesn't work for me.
I got error `operator does not exist: json = integer`.

How can I make SQL in order to obtain get this result?
I am using PostgreSQL 11.2.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which purpose has table "s_table"? It doesn't appear in your query.

Comment: Also, as far as I can see, your query should return s_id 1 and 2...? t_id=1 is 100, and the s_ids for t_id 1 are 1 and 2. Typo somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you! the header of t_id_s_id_table was the opposite. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your query's business logic - as you need to count how many `json_agg` array elements are equal to 100, your `where` clause shall be

```sql
WHERE (
  select count(*) 
  from json_array_elements_text(json_agg) jae 
  where jae::integer = 100
) > 0
```

or simpler, whether an array element equal to 100 exists

```sql
WHERE exists (
  select from json_array_elements_text(json_agg) jae 
  where jae::integer = 100
)
```

And btw better do not use the name of a function (json_agg) as a column name.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` to act on each group, and use the BOOL_OR operator to compare if any item in the group is equal to 100;

```
SELECT 
  t_id_s_id_table.s_id,
  JSON_AGG(t_value) AS json_agg
FROM
  t_id_s_id_table
LEFT JOIN
  t_table
ON
 t_table.id = t_id_s_id_table.t_id
GROUP BY 
 t_id_s_id_table.s_id
HAVING BOOL_OR(t_value=100)
```

[A DBfiddle to test with.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/76VntoRyevxkjHdH35V2cE/1)